# How do you get a documetReference from DocumentID using the flutter cloud_firestore plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a specific document in a collection. each document in that collection is named with an auto generated ID.

To achieve this, i need to get a reference to that document using its ID.

I'm using the cloud_firestore plugin for flutter. theres no such luck for a function in the docs

I'm hoping for something like this

```
var reference = Firestore.instance.refFromID(docID);
reference.delete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh hey, its pretty simple actually.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('c').document(docID).delete();
```

actually does the trick. passing the document ID into the document method gives you a reference to that document. you can do whatever you want with it afterwards